# Android App does not work correctly when delete some folders it is using

Tags: java, android, file

I get a problem is that my android app does not work correctly when user delete some folders it is using.
To solve this,every time the app access(create or modify files) the folder, a function is invoked to ensure that the folder exists.

```
    /** 
 * ensure that cache folder exists<br/>
 * */
public void ensureCacheFolderExist(){   
    File cacheFile = new File(AUDIO_CACHE_PATH);
    if (!cacheFile.exists()) {
        boolean returnValue=cacheFile.mkdirs();
        MusicUtils.logE("ensureCacheFolderExist no"+returnValue);
    } else {
        MusicUtils.logE("ensureCacheFolderExist yes");
        if (cacheFile.isFile()) {
            cacheFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

but returnValue is false all the time.
So seems this does not work.
A possible  method is  set the AUDIO_CACHE_PATH folder a hidden one.The the system default file manager can not see it.But the third-party ones can see, such as Root Explorer.
This seems not the best choice.
So is there a way to solve this?
the AUDIO_CACHE_PATH  is defined as follow(Just key point),I can make sure the problem is not caused by this:

```
    public static String getSDCardPath() {
    //String szDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    String szDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if (szDir.substring(szDir.length() - 1).equals(File.separator) == false) {
        szDir += File.separator;
    }
    return szDir;
}
public static final String DOWNLOAD_LOCAL_PATH = HardwareUtil.getSDCardPath() + "sogouappmall";     
private final String AUDIO_CACHE_PATH = DOWNLOAD_LOCAL_PATH + File.separator + ".mp3";
```

Comment: What is the value of AUDIO_CACHE_PATH?

Comment: I update this AUDIO_CACHE_PATH,I do not think this is the problem.

Comment: could it be an issue with having "." in the name, can you log/print the value of `AUDIO_CACHE_PATH` just before `mkdirs()` ?

Comment: /storage/sdcard0/sogouappmall/mp3  that is the value @ashoke

Comment: /storage/sdcard0/sogouappmall/mp3 that is the value @Okas

Answer (score 0):

unless your storage card is out of memory, i do not see a reason why it fails to do mkdirs. I hope you already have manifest permission.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and just to rule out path issues, replace

```
    File cacheFile = new File(AUDIO_CACHE_PATH);
```

with

```
    File cacheFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "sogouappmall/mp3");
```

Comment: Seems multi-process operate on a same folder or file may cause my problem. I already add uses-permission, not caused by that.

Comment: @JackieWang please my update to answer, try using `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` and if you still have issues try [ensuring the dir allocation like in android dev guide here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media).